# tar exclude is not working inside the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I am trying to create a `tar` file of a folder, which has a lot of files to be excluded. So I wrote a script (`mytar`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# more files to be included 
IGN=""
IGN="$IGN --exclude='notme.txt'"

tar --ignore-failed-read $IGN -cvf "$1" "$2"

# following command is working perfectly
# bash -c "tar --ignore-failed-read $IGN -cvf '$1' '$2'"
```

Test folder:

```
test/
    notme.txt
    test.txt
    test2.txt
```

**If I execute the script, it creates a tar file but doesn't exclude the files I have listed in `IGN`**
Apparently, the command is:

```
tar --ignore-failed-read --exclude='notme.txt' -cvf test1.tar test
```

The command is working perfectly fine if it's directly executing in the shell. Also I have found a workaround for the script: using `bash -c` in script file

```
bash -c "tar --ignore-failed-read $IGN -cvf '$1' '$2'"
```

I am wondering and trying to figure out it,

**Why this simple command is not working without `bash -c`?**
**Why it's working with `bash -c`?**

Output:
First output shouldn't container `notme.txt` file like later
[image: tar-exclude-issue-in-bash]

**UPDATE 1** script updated

Comment: I would love to hear the reason of  `-1`, could be helpful for me.

Comment: try IGN=--exclude='notme.txt', exclude the double quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the way bash expands variables in its shell.

When you set:

```
IGN="--exclude='notme.txt'"
```

it will be expanded as :

```
tar --ignore-failed-read '--exclude='\''notme.txt'\''' -cvf test1.tar test
```

And as such tar will look to exlcude a file named `\''notme.txt'\''`, which it won't find.

You may use:

```
IGN=--exclude='notme.txt'
```

which will be be interpreted correctly after shell expansion and tar will know it, but I would rather suggest you use your variable to only store the file name to be excluded:

```
IGN="notme.txt"
tar --exclude="$IGN" -cvf ./test1.tar ./*
```

Comment: `IGN=--exclude='notme.txt'` works only if filename doesn't contain space or tab and in this case the quotes are useless; `IGN=--exclude=notme.txt` will work also

Answer (score 1):

in following command single quotes are syntactical (not literal, filename argument is not literaly surounded by quotes) to prevent shell for splitting argument in the case it contains a space or a tab

```
tar --ignore-failed-read --exclude='notme.txt' -cvf test1.tar test
```

the closest is to use array instead of string variable :

```
ign=( --exclude='notme.txt' )
tar --ignore-failed-read "${ign[@]}" -cvf test1.tar test
```